# Filter current month in list

Tags: filter, view

I have single text for Month.

I want to create View with filter with Month.

Example :Month is equal to the current month
formula is  `=MONTH([Today])`

But it is not working.

Comment: It is not working since you have Month as a single text instead of Date Time field

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri So,I need to create one more column and field as a today date. And then how is the formula?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add two calculated columns that will work out the start and the end of the month. (This example uses [Due Date] but you can use any date/time column)

> "Start of Month"  =DATE(YEAR([Due Date]), MONTH([Due Date]), 1)
>
> "End of Month"    =DATE(YEAR([Due Date]), MONTH([Due Date])+1,1)-1

Then you setup a filter in your view for...

> "Start of Month" is less than or equal to [Today]  AND "End of Month"
>   is greater than or equal to [Today]

Comment: I used a very similar calculation to this, however instead of ([Due Date]) I used (Created).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the couple of columns with Date time type and calculated type in order to get this.

Check this

[A sharepoint list view of the current month](http://iwillsharemypoint.blogspot.com/2012/03/sharepoint-list-view-of-current-month.html)

[List View: Automatically Filter by Current Day, Month or Year](http://sharepointtricksortreats.blogspot.com/2013/09/list-view-automatically-filter-by.html)

Answer (score 0):

Start and end of month calculated columns can be used to fix this.

Try this [link](http://sivanesanb.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-use-filters-in-sharepoint-to.html).