# Sharepoint Column or WF to caclulate calendar items based on start time AND custom field.

Tags: calculated-column, calendar

I have a calendar for our volunteer/events mgmt. So when a volunteer works an event, a calendar item is created with that volunteer's name in a custom field.

I would really love a calculated column that can tell me how many events each volunteer has worked this month.

Like For each Volunteer, count the number of calendar items with start date current month.

Does that make sense? Any help?

working on SP 2013 Online office 365

Thank you!!

Comment: Calculated columns don't work "vertically" on other items, only "horizontally" based on the information of the current item. This will not be possible with calculated columns. You'll need to look at either CSR or workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a new standard view in your calendar list, with the following properties:

- In "Group By" section put the column that contains the name of the volunteer
- In "Totals" section, choose "Count" for the column that contains the name of the volunteer

That way you will get the view with the number of events for each volunteer.

The other part of the problem is filtering the results to the current month.
Please take a look at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/166371/15015) answer and with the information from it you should be possible to create the month filter (you need to create two additional calculated columns, as you will see at the linked answer).

Comment: Yes amazing, thank you so much. This worked beautifully. I wanted to create a workflow to email someone when the count exceeds a certain number, but since it is based on a view probably not possible.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped you. You could create the workflow which would run when the new item is created, and do the calculation in the workflow (based on the name of currently added volunteer), so when the current volunteer's number of events exceeds a certain number you send the email to specific address.

Comment: That would work perfectly - except I only want the workflow to initiate if the volunteer has completed too many events "this month" - that's where it gets tricky. Can't figure out how to include date parameters in the workflows. So it would need to count all items with VolunteerName where Start Date = This Month, and if that value was greater than 5 email someone. Know what I mean? But it's ok just getting this far is AMAZING!